# C++ - linked list - copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I am trying to implement copy constructor and I have strange problem. 
Could you point what I am doing wrong?

I get:
*double free or corruption (out): 0x08936a48*

Wrong output:

```
Constructor called...
MyList:
10 --> 20 --> 30 --> 40 --> 
MyList2:
10 --> 20 --> 30 --> 40 --> 
Destructor called...
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class SingleLinkedList{
protected:
    struct Node{
        T data;
        Node * next;
        Node() : next(nullptr) {}
        Node(const T num) : data(num), next(nullptr) {}
    };

private:
    Node * head;
    Node * tail;

public:
    SingleLinkedList();                                             // constructor
    ~SingleLinkedList();                                            // destructor
    SingleLinkedList(const SingleLinkedList &object);               // copy constructor
    SingleLinkedList& operator=(const SingleLinkedList &object);    // copy assignment

    void insert(T const& value);
    void displayList(std::ostream& stream = std::cout) const;

template <typename T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr){
    std::cout << "Constructor called..." << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::~SingleLinkedList(){
    std::cout << "Destructor called..." << std::endl;
    int index = 1;
    Node * temp = nullptr;
    while(head!=nullptr){
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        //std::cout << "Node number: " << index << " destroyed" << std::endl;
        index++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
SingleLinkedList<T>::SingleLinkedList(const SingleLinkedList<T> &oldList){
    SingleLinkedList<T> * newList = new SingleLinkedList<T>();

    // is it necessary? my constructor by default initializes head and tail with nulls
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;

    Node * temp = nullptr;
    temp = oldList.head;

    while(temp!=nullptr){
        newList->insert(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}


template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::insert(T const& value){
    Node * temp = new Node(value);
    //temp->data = value;
    //temp->next = nullptr;


    if(head==nullptr){
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else{
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void SingleLinkedList<T>::displayList(std::ostream& stream) const{
    Node * temp = nullptr;
    temp = head;

    while(temp!=nullptr){
        stream << temp->data << " --> ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    stream << std::endl;
}

int main(){

    SingleLinkedList<int> * myList = new SingleLinkedList<int>();
    SingleLinkedList<int> * myList2 = myList;

    myList->insert(10);
    myList->insert(20);
    myList->insert(30);

    myList2->insert(40);

    std::cout << "MyList:" << std::endl;
    myList->displayList();

    std::cout << "MyList2:" << std::endl;
    myList2->displayList();

    delete myList;
    delete myList2;

    return 0;
}
```

My "algorithm":
1. Create new list.
2. For each node of old list get data and insert it to new list.

I don't understand how using two different list I am deallocating the same part of memory. 
I am a student, not pro. I am asking for your understanding.

Comment: The copy constructor should initialize `this`. It's incorrect to `new` an new instance. Here you create a `newList`, fill it with elements and then discard/leak it.

Comment: Copy constructor works similar to normal constructor. Your object is already here, you don't create it with `new`. But this should not cause segfault here, because you copy empty object (so the loop is never entered).

Comment: Thank you. I  misunderstood some concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your copy ctor is really strange. Instead of adding elements to the list being constructed, you create a new list (why?) and then add elements to it. After that, you simply exit function. The new list created is left on the heap unreachable, i.e. leaked, and the list constructed remains empty.

Can you simply `insert` copied list's elements, not in a some `newList`, but in this one?

Double deletion happens for another reason: in your `main` you declare two pointers, `myList` and `myList2`, that both point to the same list in memory, and later try to delete them both. You can quickfix that by properly constructing `myList2`:

```
    SingleLinkedList<int> * myList2{new SingleLinkedList<int>(*myList)};
```

but I suggest you get rid of pointers at all in your `main`:

```
    SingleLinkedList<int> myList;
    SingleLinkedList<int> myList2(myList);
```

(And don't forget to change all `->`s into `.`s below afterwards.)

This is not Java after all, not every lifetime starts with `new`.

Comment: Thank you so much for good explanation. Of course this creation of new object inside a function was unnecessary, I misunderstood some concept.

Comment: Hope now you understand it better. :)